# Make all the Elements of Array "equal"

Tags: algorithm

I have a integer **array A** of **size N**, and I want to make all the elements of the array **equal** by performing the below operation for **minimum number of times**.

the operation is that we can Choose any element and do the bitwise **XOR** with **2^x**, where x >= 0.

At the end, I have to Return the minimum number of operations required.

---

**like for.eg**:-

eg1:
array A = {10,1,4,2}

answer: = 5

---

eg2:
array A = {5,7,4,3,5}

answer: = 4

[for better understanding visit problem link](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/equal-array/)

Comment: _"tried making each element zero"_. Why do think that would work?

Comment: With just a XOR operation, you can't solve this problem at all. You need some possibility of testing, which you don't specify.

Comment: Rephrase your question. What you are looking for is the minimum number of bit flips to make all values the same. This question has nothing to do with "C", "C++" specifically (which are different languages anyway), and you should remove hashmap and data-structure tag too, It is a pure algorithm question.

Answer (score 2):

Problem looks rather simple.

`bitwise XOR with 2^x` is inversion of `x`-th bit.

we can walk through all bit numbers and count how many array values contain bit 1 at place `x` (say `m` ones) and the rest (`n-m`) contains bit 0 at place `x`.

Hence to equalize this bit for all the values, we need `min(m, n-m)` operations.
Same for other bit numbers.

Comment: @Ajay jangid Is my answer unclear?